# corresponding columns of a data frame in python with certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this below code to get the top 5 in column G.

```
Ndata = data.sort_values( 'G', ascending=False)
newcol = Ndata.loc[:, 'G'].nlargest(5)
newcol
```

However, I am wondering, how do I get this code work to get the corresponding columns A, B and C.?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `nlargest` on the data frame and specify which column you want to take values  from. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,4,3,2,1]})
df.nlargest(n=3, columns='a')

   a  b
4  5  1
3  4  2
2  3  3
```

In your case:

```
data.nlargest(n=5, columns='G')
```

should work.

Comment: much appreciated. I got this working as I wanted.